# Rails gem dependency issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add the refinerycms gem to my existing rails app. There must be some dependancy issue that bundler is not catching because after I add:

```
gem 'refinerycms', github: 'refinery/refinerycms', branch: 'master'
gem 'refinerycms-i18n', github: 'refinery/refinerycms-i18n', branch: 'master'
```

To my rails app and then attempt to do a bundle exec rails s

I get this stack trace:

```
/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `push': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `use'
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.2/lib/rails_admin/engine.rb:28:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
```

Any thoughts on the best way to figure out where the incompatibility lies? This is for ruby 2.1.1p76 and Rails 4.0.4.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after adding the gems? did you get any dependency error messages after running `bundle install`?

Comment: see if [this](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/issues/165) helps

Comment: @asolberg What was the solution?